# Format JSON RESTful API response into a HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I am attempting to make a call to a RESTful API in which I get a JSON response. I am new to this so its bit confusing. It seems to be working. The problem I am having is trying to format the data into a readable useful format. The error I receive in the console is the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 
>  cid--N00035380
> firstlast--Bradley Byrne
> lastname--BYRNE
> party--R
> office--AL01
> gender--M
> first_elected--2013
> exit_code--20
> comments--Lost Senate primary
> phone--202-225-4931
> fax--202-225-0562
> website--https://byrne.house.gov
> webform--https://byrne.house.gov/contact/email-me
> congress_office--119 Cannon House Office Building
> bioguide_id--B001289
> votesmart_id--27584
> feccandid--H4AL01123
> twitter_id--RepByrne
> youtube_url--
> facebook_id--RepByrne
> birthdate--1955-02-16

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive" id="json_response">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="employee_table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Date of Birth</th>
                <th>Party</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Date took Office</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Website</th>
                <th>Office Location</th>
                <th>Twitter</th>
                <th>Facebook</th>
                <th>YouTube</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>

    function submit_soap(){
        var state=$('select[name=state]').val();
        $.getJSON("form_get.php",{state:state}, function(data){
            var employee_data = '';
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                employee_data += '<tr>';
                employee_data += '<td>'+value.firstlast+'</td>'
                employee_data += '<td>'+value.birthdate+'</td>'
                employee_data += '<td>'+value.party+'</td>'
                employee_data += '<td>'+value.office+'</td>'
                employee_data += '<td>'+value.gender+'</td>'
                employee_data += '<td>'+value.firstelectoff+'</td>'
                employee_data += '<td>'+value.phone+'</td>'
                employee_data += '<td>'+value.website+'</td>'   
                employee_data += '<td>'+value.congress_office+'</td>'
                employee_data += '<td>'+value.twitter_id+'</td>'
                employee_data += '<td>'+value.facebook_id+'</td>'
                employee_data += '<td>'+value.youtube_url+'</td>'

            });
            $('#employee_table').append(employee_data);
    });
}
</script>

<?php
try{
$state=$_GET['state'];
$url = 'https://www.opensecrets.org/api/?method=getLegislators&id='.$state.'&apikey=************&output=json';
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$json_array=json_decode($response,true); 
function display_array_recursive($json_rec){
    if($json_rec){
        foreach($json_rec as $key=> $value){
            if(is_array($value)){
                display_array_recursive($value);
            }else{
                echo $key.'--'.$value.'<br>';
            }   
        }   
    }   
}
display_array_recursive($json_array);
}catch(Exception $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

***EDIT*** I made the change to .get to .getJSON. The errors went away. Unfortunately, my table still isn't loading the records. I added the HTML for the table. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks for the help everyone!

[API Documentation](https://www.opensecrets.org/api/?method=getLegislators&output=doc)

Comment: You aren't parsing the response. You need to use `$.getJSON` or manually call `JSON.parse` on the string you get back.

Comment: Thanks Jared. I have been all over the place trying to figure this out. I knew my problem was parsing the data, but I'm not sure what that would look like. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I did. Where you have `$.get` you need to replace it (I'm assuming jQuery) with `$.getJSON` which will parse the response for you.

Comment: Thanks. Whelp that took care of all the errors in the console but my page isnt loading the data into the table. SMH I have been pulling my hairout.

Comment: You're trying to do too much at once. You wrote all your code and then ran it to see if it works. That sometimes works, if you're doing something you've done a million times already. But that's not how you do something you don't know how to do already. Break it up into atomic steps. You're trying to 1. Fetch data from an API 2. Turn the data into a HTML table 3. Render that table to the DOM. You're lost because you don't know which step in the chain is failing. So do them one at a time. Can I fetch data and print it to the console? Check. Can I access specific properties of that data? Does...

Comment: ...`console.log(data, typeof data);` print both the data and the expected type? You would have had a better handle on your first problem when you saw it print 'string' instead of 'object'. If I print my table to the console does it look right? Is the HTML well-formed? Ok, if not, can I just turn the first record in the data (ignoring the rest of it for now) and print *that* to the console? Does it look right? Once you've figured out that the table is being constructed properly as far as you can tell, *then* try appending it to the document.